# Android WebView with JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

In a `WebView` in my app I cannot run `JavaScript`. I tried many ways and searched many Stackoverflow pages to find the answer. It cannot even show me a simple alert message.

Here's my code :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_webviewac);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Eeverything is fine in the browser but in a `WebView` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will solve the problem

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://syllabkerala.in");
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //hide loading image
                    findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //show webview
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```